# Writing SQL queries without table access full

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle, entity-framework

**TL;DR** I'm using `EntityFramework 5.0` with `Oracle` and need to query a table for two columns only using index with `NVL` of two columns.

Details after hours of attempts... I'll try to organize it as possible.

The **desired SQL query** should be:

```sql
SELECT t.Code, NVL(t.Local, t.Global) Description
FROM   Shows t
Where  t.Code = 123
```

So what is the problem? If I want to use `Context.Shows.Parts.SqlQuery(query)` I must return the whole row(`*`), but then I get ***Table Access Full***, so I must return only the desired columns.

The next thing(Actually there were a lot of tries before the following...) that I've tried which gives a very close results was using the ***null-coalescing operator***(`??`) :

```C#
Context.Shows.Where(x => x.Code == 123)
             .Select(x => new { x.Code, Description = x.Local ?? x.Global);
```

But the SQL it's using is complicated using `case & when` and not using my Index on     `Code, Nvl(Local, Global)` which is critical!

My next step was using ***Database.SqlQuery***

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<Tuple<int, string>>("the Raw-SQLQuery above");
```

But I get an error that `Tuple` must not be abstract and **must have default ctor**(it doesn't).

Final step which I dislike is **creating a class** which has only those two properites(`Code, Description`), now... it works great, but I don't want to write a class for each query like that.

Ideas?

Comment: You can try writing your own Tuple implementation which has default constructor and is a class.

Comment: _"Final step which I dislike is creating a class...  but I don't want to write a class for each query like that"_

Comment: You don't have to write new class for each query, but write only one generic reusable class, and use it as you are using Touple in your example.

Comment: What is the complex query being generated with Case and When? You may be able to create a function-based index that can be used for it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, Unfortunately I don't have internet connection at my workstation and it's a lot to copy. anyway, bottom line that it's not good because it's not using the right index.

Comment: @jure, as in the answer, the names must match.

Comment: Can't you alias the resulting fields in SQL . SELECT Code AS Item1, ....

Comment: @jure, I don't want `ItemX`... Someone will need to maintain it in the future(including me...)

Comment: It's unusual for the items in the SELECT clause to impact the access methods.  This implies that your good query plan is using an index full scan; which may be better than a full table scan, but may also be much worse than an index range scan.  How many rows does the SELECT return?  If it's a very small number, and the query plan is using an index full scan, there may be some better optimization.

Answer (score 2):

This is a no-solution answer.

I think whatever you try, you can't do that. Even if you define your own mutable generic Tuple, it will failed since the name of the property must [match the name of the column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> SqlQuery(String, Object[]): Creates a raw SQL query that will
>   return elements of the given generic type. The type can be any type
>   that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from
>   the query, or can be a simple primitive type.

I think the best you can do is creating your own generic method for querying the database via classic `Command` and `ExecuteReader` pattern. Untested, but you get the idea:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T>> SqlQuery<T>(this DbContext context, string sql)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.NextResult())
        {
            yield return new Tuple<T>((T)reader[0]);
        }
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> SqlQuery<T1, T2>(this DbContext context, string sql)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.NextResult())
        {
            yield return new Tuple<T1, T2>((T1)reader[0], (T2)reader[1]);
        }
    }
}
```